# MongoDB Program New Database Authentication Fails

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a remote tenant database application using MongoDB with authentication enabled.  During run-time, I have to programmatically create a new tenant database, create a new tenant database user, create a new collection, and write to the new database with user metadata.  My problem is that I am not setting up the tenant user authorization correctly.  I am able to create the new tenant database and a database user with role credentials "readWrite".  I also can correctly write the document to the "users" collection.  If I use my admin credentials, I can access the Tenant database and examine the users document with no issue.  However, if I try to later access the database with the newly created database user credentials I get an incorrect user credentials exception.  Below is my code that creates the new tenant database,

```
 MongoCredential adminCredentials = MongoCredential
      .createCredential(adminuid, admindb, adminpw.toCharArray());
 ServerAddress adminSA = new ServerAddress(mongoConnectionUri, mongoPort);

 // Create the Mongo Password Vault Client & Document Template
 MongoClient adminclient = new MongoClient(adminSA, Arrays.asList(adminCredtials)):
 MongoClient adminclient MongoClient(adminSA,Arrays.asList(adminCredentials));
 DB tenant = adminclient.getDB(tenantdb);

 // Create pwvdb user
 DBObject pwvdbrole = new BasicDBObject();
 pwvdbrole.put("role", pwvrole);
 pwvdbrole.put("db", pwvdb);

 ArrayList<DBObject> pwvdbroles = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
 pwvdbroles.add(pwvdbrole);

 DBObject pwvaultcmd = new BasicDBObject();
 pwvaultcmd.put("createUser", pwvuid);
 pwvaultcmd.put("pwd", pwvpw);
 pwvaultcmd.put("roles", pwvdbroles);

 CommandResult result = tenant.command(pwvaultcmd);
 if (result.ok()) {
      System.out.println("Tenant Credentials: OK");
 } else {
      System.out.println("Tenant Credentials Error: " +
      result.getErrorMessage());
 }

 // Create users Collection
 DBCollection tenantCollection =
      tenant.getCollection(tenantcollection);

 // Create user default credentials & update user collection
 BasicDBObject userdocument = new BasicDBObject();
 userdocument.put("firstname", userfirstname);
 userdocument.put("lastname", userlastname);
 userdocument.put("email", useremail);
 userdocument.put("username", username);
 userdocument.put("password", pwencoder.encode(userpassword));
 userdocument.put("role", Integer.parseInt(userrole));

 // Create admin web portal users uid/pw
 tenantCollection.insert(userdocument);

 pwvclient.close();
```

Because the client is remote, I use my admin userid, pw, and db for the credentials.  However, the MongoDB tenant client is setup using the new tenant database name.  This is probably where I am going wrong but I don't know how to remotely access the database with a user I have not created yet.  These databases are created at run time and I do not know the name of the tenant user when the application starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get it to work.  The two key things I want to point out is the adminops and testops MongoDB templates.  Notice that in adminops I used my MongoDB admin credentials but pointed to the testdb.  In testops I used my new testdb credentials and point to testdb as well.  My error was with adminops.  I used the admindb which was incorrect.  Also getting the roleobj and cmd was a little tricky but I eventially figured it out.

```
package com.belcan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.CommandResult;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class PreConfigTestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Fire off Spring Boot & Embedded Linux
        SpringApplication.run(PreConfigTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {

        String testdb = "testdb";
        String testuid = "skm";
        String testpw = "password";

        // Set up credentials
        MongoCredential admincredentials = MongoCredential
                .createCredential(adminuid, admindb, adminpw.toCharArray());
        ServerAddress adminsa = new ServerAddress(mongoConnectionUri, mongoPort);


        // Create the Mongo Client & Document Template
        MongoClient adminclient = new MongoClient(adminsa,Arrays.asList(admincredentials));
        MongoOperations adminops = new MongoTemplate(adminclient, testdb);

        // First create new user
        DBObject roleobj = new BasicDBObject();
        roleobj.put("role", "readWrite");
        roleobj.put("db", "testdb");

        ArrayList<DBObject> array = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
        array.add(roleobj);

        DBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject();
        cmd.put("createUser", testuid);
        cmd.put("pwd", testpw);
        cmd.put("roles", array);

        // Create new User
        CommandResult result = (CommandResult) adminops.executeCommand(cmd);

        // check to see if command is ok
        if (result.ok()) {
            System.out.println("createUser Command: OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("createUser Error:" + result.getErrorMessage());
        }

        // switch to testdb
        MongoOperations testops = new MongoTemplate(adminclient, testdb);

        // Create the user object
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstname("mickey");
        user.setLastname("mouse");
        user.setEmail("mmouse@gmail.com");
        user.setUsername("mmouse");
        user.setPassword("mmouse1");
        user.setRole("USER");
        user.setStatus("ACTIVE");

        // Now save it
        testops.save(user, "users");

        // Close Database Connection
        adminclient.close();


        //
        // Now see if we can open the file with the new uid/pw
        //

        // Set up credentials
        MongoCredential testcredentials = MongoCredential
                .createCredential(testuid, testdb, testpw.toCharArray());
        ServerAddress testsa = new ServerAddress(mongoConnectionUri, mongoPort);


        // Create the Mongo Client & Document Template
        MongoClient testclient = new MongoClient(testsa,Arrays.asList(testcredentials));
        MongoOperations myops = new MongoTemplate(testclient, testdb);

        User myuser = new User();
        myuser.setFirstname("Daffy");
        myuser.setLastname("Duck");
        myuser.setEmail("dduck@gmail.com");
        myuser.setUsername("dduck");
        myuser.setPassword("dduck1");
        myuser.setRole("USER");
        myuser.setStatus("ACTIVE");

        // Now save it
        myops.save(myuser,"users");

        // Lets print it out
        System.out.println("Print Results");
        ArrayList<User> userout = (ArrayList<User>) myops.findAll(User.class, "users");
        for (int i = 0; i < userout.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(userout.get(i));

        }

        System.out.println("\n\nAll Done....");

        // Close the database
        testclient.close();

    }

        // MongoDB Connection URI
        @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}") 
        private String mongoConnectionUri;

        // MongoDB Connection Port
        @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
        private int mongoPort;

        // MongoDB userid
        @Value("${mongo.server.admin.db}")
        private String admindb;

        // MongoDB admin password
        @Value("${mongo.server.admin.pw}")
        private String adminpw;

        // MongoDB admin userid
        @Value("${mongo.server.admin.uid}")
        private String adminuid;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two different places for user permissions to be created, which can be confusing. Both can be done dynamically in your code.

### ***User roles in tenant DB***

The easiest option is for you to create the user you want in the tenant DB. You should use the [runCommand call](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/commands/) with the document structure for the [createUser command documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createUser/). You would create this user in the tenant DB. The role should be readWrite or any others documented.

Then later you would authenticate for the user and password for that same DB.

You can also centralize all of your user management in the Admin DB with each createUser call enumerating the roles for each DB/role pair you want. Let me know if you need that explanation. It works basically the same way to create users there and authenticate against that DB also. Then you switch to the DB you want to access on the same MongoClient.

I could not post 2 other helpful links because of strange limitation on posting more than 2 links if I am not an active enough poster (10 reputation).